# How to query a FireStore datamodel with 2 related collections for only documents if a field exists in another collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have 2 collection:

1. categories
   id:
   name:
2. books
   id:
   name:
   categories: []

a book has an title and an array of the categories it belongs to.

I want make a query to show only all the categories if there a related book.
Otherwise a user sees category 'x' and when going to then next screen, there are 0 related books. This i don't want, so category 'x' should not be in the list of all the avaiable categories on that screen.

How to do that? Is my datamodel the right one?

Thanks inadvance for the answers ;)

Comment: Could you share the full data structure for this categories?

Comment: Thanks José for your reply. This is the full dat structure for categories. Only a name.

Answer (score 1):

In relational DBs this would be done with a `Join` but the issue is that Firestore  doesn't have joins.

So this query will need to be performed manually by getting all the books, concatenating categories arrays and then removing repeated values.